# How to make custom iOS apps easier for Spotlight to find

Tags: ios, testing, metadata, spotlight

I write lots of little test apps on my devices. Is there some metadata I can add to the app so it appears more readily in Spotlight searches?

For instance, I made a laundry timer app named Lavado

[image: Lavado app icon]

Can I make it appear in Spotlight searches when I search for "timer" or "laundry"?

This is not for the Apple App Store, just on my devices.

Answer (score 8):

Spotlight searches both names as they appear in SpringBoard (your home screen) and their full App Store names.

So if your application full name is "Lavado timer laundry test" it will appear when you are lookin for "timer" for example (Your spring board name can still be "Lavado").