# Setup keywords for local spotlight search

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, spotlight

My application name is quite long... "Super Duper Game V2". I've set the bundle display name to "SDGV2". This means that the text underneath the iOS app displays "SDGV2", but I want the local spotlight search (when the user pulls down from the home springboard) to be able to find the game with either "SDGV2" or "Super Duper Game V2". Are there keys to the Info.plist I can add to index spotlight with both app names so the user can easily find it?

EDIT:
My Info.plist currently contains the shortened name in 'Bundle Display Name', and the long version in 'Bundle Name'. Only the shortened name works for finding the app in local search when I deploy it to my device.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182852/ios-change-app-name-for-homescreen-and-spotlight | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249931/how-to-make-custom-ios-apps-easier-for-spotlight-to-find

Comment: Unfortunately neither seem to be working for me, edited question to clarify more.

Comment: Have you found out how to make this work? I'm struggling to make my app appear when searched with "food". All our competitors' apps appear, but not ours :( Our App Store Connect name has "food", keyword has "food" but still doesn't appear in Applications section of Spotlight search results.. sad.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, there are only 2 parameters Spotlight searches by — first one is your app's Bundle Display Name and the second one is your app's Apple Store Name. You can set one of them as SDGV2 and another one as Super Duper Game V2, only then Spotlight will be able to recognise both of them.

Comment: What fields in the info.plist correspond to this?

Comment: Just to back this up. Spotlight will use both your iTunesConnect name (setup on iTunesConnect) and your bundle display name (setup in the plist). It's worth noting that this only works if the build on your device is from the app store however, if its a debug build installed via xcode it seems to only search by bundle display name